# Exporting Highchart To PDF Results in 2 Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

When we are exporting our charts in PDF format we are getting what looks like 2 pages in a PDF file. Live demo of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/nFY9B/). We are not sure what is causing this.

When we export we are altering the chart properties like so:

```
chartMainLoc.exportChart(
    {
    type: &#39;application/pdf&#39;,
    sourceHeight: this.chartHeight,
    sourceWidth: this.chartWidth,
    scale: 1
    },
    {
    title: {
        text: &#39;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight:bold&quot;>Labor Force, Employment and Unemployment for Pinellas County in June, 2013&lt;/span>&lt;br />&lt;br />&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight:bold;font-size:9pt&quot;>Labor Force Graph&lt;/span>&lt;br />&lt;br />&lt;span style=&quot;font-size:10px; font-weight:normal&quot;>The graph below shows the monthly not seasonally adjusted Labor Force, Employment and Unemployment data for Pinellas County in June, 2013.&lt;/span>&#39;
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: &#39;Source: Labor Market Statistics, Local Area Unemployment Statistics Program and Online Advertised Job Data&lt;br />Downloaded: 06/10/2014 4:20 PM&#39;
    },
    legend: {
        y: -50
    },
    chart: {
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingBottom: 10,
        shadow: false,
        height: chartMainLoc.chartHeight + 20
    }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is related with known bug, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1957

Comment: Okay. Last change on that was a year ago.

Comment: How to fix this now if was fixed a year ago and closed?

Comment: Well it should be fixed in the 4.0.1 version, can you replicate your demo as live, then I will reopen this ticket

Comment: Live demo link in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/nFY9B/ it does appear that jsFiddle is down currently but that is the code we are using.

Comment: Were you able to replicate the issue?